# Mixing Types in Referenced Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Users in my app can create *Projects* and *Tasks*. *Tasks* can be either alone or in a *Project* that is a container for *Tasks*.

**Projects**

```
const projectSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
});
```

**Tasks**

```
const taskSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Project", required: false },
    authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
});
```

It's kind of a social platform and Users can share on their timeline either the whole *Project*, one *Task* from this *Project*, or a single *Task*. Embedded in a *Post*, that can be also just text without anything else.

**Post**

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    content: { type: String, required: false },
    authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Project", required: false } },
    taskId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Task", required: false } }
});
```

Of course it has to be at least something but if the *User* choose to embed a *Task* or a *Project*, it has to be only one of them. Something like:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    content: { type: String, required: false },
    authorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    media: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: ["Project", "Task"], required: false } },
});
```

But I'm guessing it's not the good syntax at all, what is a good way to make it work? Also I would like my users to be able to post any type of media, not just *Task* or *Project* but also *Images*, *Videos*, *Links*...

Comment: Ok, So what is the question here?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks bud, I forgot to copy/paste the last part =)